# Configuring elastic search to listen on 0.0.0.0:9200 (IPV4)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've been trying to get elastic search (running behind a vpn) to listen to incoming requests from other machines on `port 9200` using `ipv4`. Without modifying the default `elasticsearch.yml`, I ran `netstat` and received:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      8079/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      8079/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      8079/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      8079/java
```

With the default settings, I could `curl` elastic search fine from inside the machine, but could not connect curl it from outside using `curl -XGET [IP]:9200` (`curl: (7) Failed to connect to [IP] port 9200: Connection refused`)

I set `network.host: 0.0.0.0`, stopped and started elastic search `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service` and waited for a minute or two, but nothing was listening on `0.0.0.0:9200`. I've also tried `_local_:ipv4` and `0.0.0.0:ipv4` with no luck.

---

I added `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to jvm.options and now I am getting (with `# network.port` commented out):

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11131/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11131/java
```

I tried to set `network.host: 0.0.0.0` again and restart the service but now I don't see it listening to any ports.

In the log files I receive an error `[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`

Setting `cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1` fixed it. Works.

Comment: Does your firewall allow incoming requests to port 9200 from external IP?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Yes, I made sure the port wasnt blocked by a firewall

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16994)?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Thanks! I am getting closer now. Updated above.

Answer (score 3):

I added `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to `jvm.options`. Also added `cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1` to elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: File /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch in Rocky Linux: ES_JAVA_OPTS=" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true "

Comment: @JuhaTuomala - Your step is working fine in the Elasticsearch 8.11 version in Amazon Linux 2023 - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values you can add `:ipv4` or `:ipv6` suffixes to `network.host`, `network.bind_host`, `network.publish_host`, like: `_en0:ipv4_`.